# Optimize C++ template executions

Tags: c++, algorithm, templates, optimization

I am working on project where the performance is critical. The application is processing a huge amount of data. Code is written in C++ and I need to do some changes.

There is given following code (It is NOT my code and I simplified it to minimum):

```
void process<int PARAM1, int PARAM2>() {
    // processing the data
}

void processTheData (int param1, int param2) { // wrapper

    if (param1 == 1 && param2 == 1) { // Ugly looking block of if's
        process<1, 1>();
    else if(param1 == 1 && param2 == 2) {
        process<1, 2>();
    else if(param1 == 1 && param2 == 3) {
        process<1, 3>();
    else if(param1 == 1 && param2 == 4) {
        process<1, 4>();
    else if(param1 == 2 && param2 == 1) {
        process<2, 1>();
    else if(param1 == 2 && param2 == 2) {
        process<2, 2>();
    else if(param1 == 2 && param2 == 3) {
        process<2, 3>();
    else if(param1 == 2 && param2 == 4) {
        process<2, 4>();
    }   // and so on....

}
```

And the main function:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    factor1 = atoi(argv[1]);
    factor2 = atoi(argv[2]);

    // choose some optimal param1 and param2
    param1 = choseTheOptimal(factor1, factor2);
    param2 = choseTheOptimal(factor1, factor2);

    processTheData(param1, param2); //start processing

    return 0;
}
```

Hopefully the code looks clear.

The functions:

- **process** is the core function that is processing the data,
- **processTheData** is a wrapper of the process function.

There is a limited number of values that the params (*param1* and *param2*) takes (Let's say about 10 x 10).

The values of *param1* and *param2* are NOT known before execution.

If I simply rewrite the **process** function so it uses the function parameters instead of template constants (means *process(int PARAM1, int PARAM2)*) then the processing is about 10 times slower.

Because of the above the *PARAM1* and *PARAM2* must be the constant of **process** function.

Is there any smart way to get rid of this ugly block of if's located in **processTheData** function?

Comment: The short answer: no there isn't. Sure, you can restructure it so that it's ugly in some other way. Perhaps it can be cleaned up with some macros. But this is fundamental to C++. Something, somewhere, needs to generate all this code bloat, for optimization purposes, and conditionally execute it. The End.

Comment: Out of curiosity, if you make the the parameters `const` do it help at all?

Comment: Unfortunately the const don't help. I was thinking about metaprogamming solution but I don't have experience in that.

Comment: It should be completely sufficient to create a mapping from the input to the respective output (well, since the method is `void`, side-effects would be more correct here). Conversion of a pair of integers in limited ranges into a single integer is fairly simple to achieve and in combination with an array as lookup-structure should do the job (depends on the application of the code you presented though).

Comment: @SamVarshavchik No, this is C++.  You can generate quadratic amounts of code and dispatch to it easily.

Comment: Why is is 10x slower as a function?  What does your release build profiling tell you is the bottleneck?  Is it memory accesses, branches, etc.  Your assertion of a 10x slow down on function calls vs templates is quite the claim and seems to say that process() is very, very fast per iteration.

Comment: Looks like XY problem and problem is in rewriting of template to regular function

Comment: @Slava not really, I've seen many problems just like this.  A classic example is per-pixel operations.  Or many kinds of signal processing, where a fixed width window leads to a much more efficient implementation (and the compiler can take nearly identical code, and with the fixed width window optimize it a ridiculous amount).

Comment: @Yakk cascade if with 100 steps would be faster than one short function vs template? I would like to see that implementation.

Comment: @Slava First, 100 steps of an if is going to be what, a few milliseconds even with horrible branch prediction?  Why do you think the function is *short* in time it takes to run?

Comment: @Yakk per-pixel operation is a long function? Anyway I would like to see actual code where `templated` would be 10 times faster.

Comment: @Slava No, the per-pixel operation might be executed a million or billion times in a loop.  The values being compile time constants change how things work.  You can write a branch-full per-pixel operation with a myraid of ifs, and if the things being branched on are constant the compiler dead-code eliminates every branch, and then can often vectorize the adjacent per-pixel calls.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like this.

```
#include <array>
#include <utility>

template<int PARAM1, int PARAM2>
void process() {
    // processing the data
}

// make a jump table to call process<X, Y> where X is known and Y varies    
template<std::size_t P1, std::size_t...P2s>
constexpr auto make_table_over_p2(std::index_sequence<P2s...>)
{
    return std::array<void (*)(), sizeof...(P2s)>
    {
        &process<int(P1), int(P2s)>...
    };
}

// make a table of jump tables to call process<X, Y> where X and Y both vary    
template<std::size_t...P1s, std::size_t...P2s>
constexpr auto make_table_over_p1_p2(std::index_sequence<P1s...>, std::index_sequence<P2s...> p2s)
{
    using element_type = decltype(make_table_over_p2<0>(p2s));
    return std::array<element_type, sizeof...(P1s)>
    {
        make_table_over_p2<P1s>(p2s)...
    };
}


void processTheData (int param1, int param2) { // wrapper

    // make a 10x10 jump table
    static const auto table = make_table_over_p1_p2(
        std::make_index_sequence<10>(), 
        std::make_index_sequence<10>()
    ) ;

    // todo - put some limit checks here

    // dispatch
    table[param1][param2]();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is what I call the matic switch.  It takes a runtime value (within a specified range), and turns it into a compile time value.

```
namespace details 
{
  template<std::size_t I>
  using index_t = std::integral_constant<std::size_t, I>;

  template<class F>
  using f_result = std::result_of_t< F&&(index_t<0>) >;
  template<class F>
  using f_ptr = f_result<F>(*)(F&& f);
  template<class F, std::size_t I>
  f_ptr<F> get_ptr() {
    return [](F&& f)->f_result<F> {
      return std::forward<F>(f)(index_t<I>{});
    };
  }
  template<class F, std::size_t...Is>
  auto dispatch( F&& f, std::size_t X, std::index_sequence<Is...> ) {
    static const f_ptr<F> table[]={
      get_ptr<F, Is>()...
    };
    return table[X](std::forward<F>(f));
  }
}
template<std::size_t max, class F>
details::f_result<F>
dispatch( F&& f, std::size_t I ) {
  return details::dispatch( std::forward<F>(f), I, std::make_index_sequence<max>{} );
}
```

what this does is build a jump table to convert runtime data to a compile time constant.  I use a lambda, because it makes it nice and generic, and pass it an integral constant.  An integral constant is a runtime stateless object whose type carries the constant with it.

An example use:

```
template<std::size_t a, std::size_t b>
void process() {
    static_assert( sizeof(int[a+1]) + sizeof(int[b+1]) >= 0 );
}

constexpr int max_factor_1 = 10;
constexpr int max_factor_2 = 10;

int main() {
    int factor1 = 1;
    int factor2 = 5;

    dispatch<max_factor_1>(
      [factor2](auto factor1) {
        dispatch<max_factor_2>(
          [factor1](auto factor2) {
            process< decltype(factor1)::value, decltype(factor2)::value >();
          },
          factor2
        );
      },
      factor1
    );
}
```

where `max_factor_1` and `max_factor_2` are `constexpr` values or expressions.

This uses C++14 for auto lambdas and constexpr implicit cast from integral constants.

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fd763174759f2bea).

Comment: ow! my eyes hurt :)

Comment: Ugh - I don't even know if I trust OP's initial assertion of where the bottlenecks are and this code... hide it 3 layers deep in headers so I never need to see it again :)

Comment: @MichaelDorgan The other way that I think I almost prefer is `switch_upto<max_factor_1>(factor1)` returning a lambda that in turn does the magic switch.  Then I could get `switch_upto<max_factor_1, max_factor_2>(factor1, factor2)` and pass that a lambda that gets passed 2 arguments...

Comment: @Yakk I actually think there should be language feature or standard idiom for this kind of thing. It seems to come up a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with. It uses less fancy features (only `enable_if`, no variadic templates or function pointers) but it is also less generic. Pasting the code into [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/XXWJUr) indicates that compilers are able to optimize this completely away for the example code which may have a performance advantage in the real code.

```
#include <type_traits>

template <int param1, int param2>
void process() {
    static_assert(sizeof(int[param1 + 1]) + sizeof(int[param2 + 1]) > 0);
}

template <int limit2, int param1, int param2>
std::enable_if_t<(param2 > limit2)> pick_param2(int) {
    static_assert("Invalid value for parameter 2");
}

template <int limit2, int param1, int param2>
std::enable_if_t<param2 <= limit2> pick_param2(int p) {
    if (p > 0) {
        pick_param2<limit2, param1, param2 + 1>(p - 1);
    } else {
        process<param1, param2>();
    }
}

template <int limit1, int limit2, int param>
std::enable_if_t<(param > limit1)> pick_param1(int, int) {
    static_assert("Invalid value for parameter 1");
}

template <int limit1, int limit2, int param>
std::enable_if_t<param <= limit1> pick_param1(int p1, int p2) {
    if (p1 > 0) {
        pick_param1<limit1, limit2, param + 1>(p1 - 1, p2);
    } else {
        pick_param2<limit2, param, 0>(p2);
    }
}

template <int limit_param1, int limit_param2>
void pick_params(int param1, int param2) {
    pick_param1<limit_param1, limit_param2, 0>(param1, param2);
}

int main() {
    int p1 = 3;
    int p2 = 5;
    pick_params<10, 10>(p1, p2);
}
```

I'd be interested in profiling results.